# Error using google map api url in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, json, google-maps

I used this particular url "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=MY_QUERY&key=API_KEY" in angularjs to get a json response.

When used in $http.get(url) in angularjs it gives an error response. But the above link opens in a browser. Does the above problem has anything to do with the key used. Please help me with the problem.

Comment: what error you are getting in your browser console ?

Comment: The status parameter of $http.get function returns a -1 value. I used a geocode url which returned the json script successfully